# How to create a wait in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm filling out a form but 1 part takes a longer time, and it messes up the whole thing. I'm using splinter in python 2.7 on mac. I need help and any help would be helpful.

Comment: Didn't think of it that way, thank you bro.

Answer (score 0):

```
time.sleep(t)
```

where "t" is the number of seconds you want the program to sleep

D.

Comment: It's already flagged as duplicate. Let's not spam answers, for questions which already have great answers on a site.

Comment: @igormilla sorry, didn't notice it was flagged as duplicate...